# How do I remove the process currently using a port on localhost in Windows?

Tags: windows, cmd, localhost, port, command-prompt

How can I remove the current process/application which is already assigned to a port?

For example: `localhost:8080`

Comment: npx kill-port 8080

Comment: apparently, npx kill-port is either not working at all or can't kill processes that have elevated privileges, for Windows 10.

Comment: @Pavindu just tested it works on Windows Server 2016 without no problems, even when the task is running with elevated priviledges.

Comment: I got this working for myself `lsof -i :3000 | awk '/[1-9]/ {print $2}' | xargs kill -9` there is probably an easier way to do it

Answer (score 2756, accepted):

**Step 1:**

Open up cmd.exe (note: you *may* need to run it as an administrator, but this isn't always necessary), then run the below command:

> `netstat -ano | findstr :<PORT>`

(Replace `<PORT>` with the port number you want, but keep the colon)

[image]

The area circled in red shows the PID (process identifier). Locate the PID of the process that's using the port you want.

**Step 2:**

Next, run the following command:

> `taskkill /PID <PID> /F`

(No colon this time)

[image]

Lastly, you can check whether the operation succeeded or not by re-running the command in "Step 1". If it was successful you shouldn't see any more search results for that port number.

Comment: @HardikMandankaa Is it the _same_ process? Some software may be set up to relaunch the listening process if it is killed.

Comment: I had to enter escape characters when running taskkill: `taskkill //PID 12552 //F`

Comment: accepted answer will not work for services which are set up to restart on failure (this is not linux)

Comment: I got processId 0 on port 80. If I try to kill it I get "ERROR: The process with PID 0 could not be terminated.
Reason: This is critical system process. Taskkill cannot end this process."

Comment: The colon symbol has to be in a very specific place. Can't change spaces or this command won't work. Otherwise this also works without colon: "netstat -ano | findstr 8080"

Comment: What work for me is `taskkill //PID myProcessId -F`

Comment: 2020-04-03, Windows10, Python 3.6.6, using Git Bash: confirming that using the double forward slash worked for me as well. I needed to kill a Flask app process on `localhost:5000` that didn't terminate. e.g. `taskkill //F //PID 16660` .

Comment: i think you meant PID_NUMBER and not PORT_NUMBER in ``taskkill /PID PORT_NUMBER /F``

Comment: with colon not working netstat -ano | findstr :<portNumber>, without colon working fine netstat -ano | findstr <portNumber>

Comment: I used :  netstat -ano to get the PID number and kill the process using : taskkill /PID <PID> /F .

Comment: what are the ano flag

Comment: I ran it in PowerShell, and `taskkill` needed to be run in an elevated shell.

Comment: What should be done if netstat in Step 1 doesn't return anything, but IIS Express still complains that the port is in use?

Comment: What's the problem @H Nazmul Hassan? run it as **administrator**

Comment: You can also use "-" instead of "/". You don't have to escape the slashes and for me "-" is more intuitive

Answer (score 562):

I know that is really old question, but found pretty easy to remember, fast command to kill apps that are using port.

Requirements: npm@5.2.0^ version

```
npx kill-port 8080
```

You can also read more about kill-port here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/kill-port

Comment: I can't believe I didn't know about this, so useful thank you!

Comment: I can't believe I never scrolled down to see this... I have come to this SO page so many times when I forget the bash command... This is so much easier to remember

Comment: this doesn't work

Comment: @Piliponful, you need npm installed, its a node.js package manager

Answer (score 222):

There are two ways to kill the processes

**Option 01 - Simplest and easiest**

*Requirement : npm@5.2.0^ version*


Open the Command prompt as Administrator and give the following command with the port (Here the port is 8080)

```
npx kill-port 8080
```

---

**Option 02 - Most commonly used**

- Step 01
  Open Windows command prompt as Administrator
- Step 02
  Find the PID of the port you want to kill with the below command: Here port is 8080

```
netstat -ano|findstr "PID :8080"
```

> TCP 0.0.0.0:8080 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING 18264

- Step 03
  Kill the PID you received above with the below command (In my case PID is 18264)

```
taskkill /PID 18264 /f
```

Comment: Option 1 is the best answer in the world. I'm wondering why isn't this the first choice.

Answer (score 207):

**With Windows 10/11 default tools:**

**✔ Step one:**

*Open Windows PowerShell **as Administrator***

**✔ Step two:**

*Find the ProcessID for the port you need to kill (e.g. 3000)*

```
netstat -aon | findstr 3000
```

> TCP    0.0.0.0:3000  **LISTEN   1234**

**✔ Step three:**

*Kill the zombie process:*

```
taskkill /f /pid 1234
```

where "**1234**" is your ProcessID (aka PID)

****Extra tip if you use Windows Subsystem for Linux (Ubuntu WSL):***

**✔ Step one:**

```
sudo lsof -t -i:3000
```

**✔ Step two:**

```
sudo kill -9 1234
```

Comment: How to automate the process and combine these two commands together in one bat file if there is no possibility to view the cmd output and then write new command manually?

Comment: @Serob_b  
`set /p port="Enter port: "` -> Input port  
`FOR /F "tokens=5" %%T IN ('netstat -aon ^| findstr %port% ') DO (
SET /A ProcessId=%%T) &GOTO SkipLine`   
`:SkipLine` -> Extracts PID into variable  
`taskkill /f /pid %ProcessId%` -> Kills the task  
`cmd /k`  -> Keep the window open

Comment: @Vikrant Is there a way to hide all the commands and just show "Enter port: " and "SUCCESS: The process with PID 35264 has been terminated." ?

Comment: @CrazyVideoGamez `@echo off`

Answer (score 191):

*Step 1 (same is in accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39633428/5292302) written by [KavinduWije](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3626371/kavinduwije)):*

> ```
> netstat -ano | findstr :yourPortNumber
> ```

*Change in Step 2 to:*

```
tskill typeyourPIDhere
```

*Note*: `taskkill` is not working in some git bash terminal

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me. I'm using GIT Bash.

Answer (score 116):

**If you are using GitBash**

*Step one:*

```
netstat -ano | findstr :8080
```

*Step two:*

```
taskkill /PID typeyourPIDhere /F
```

(`/F` forcefully terminates the process)

Comment: @kylexy1357 try with a single slash. The "double slash" is an escape character that precedes the /, which is not needed for some shells

Answer (score 91):

The simplest solution — the only one I can ever remember:

**In Windows Powershell**

Say we want to stop a process on port **8080**

1. Get the process:

```
netstat -ano | findstr :8080
```

2. Stop the process

```
stop-process 82932
```

Comment: this one helped me! I'm on Win10 ~

Comment: need to run from powershell (not git bash)

Answer (score 61):

If you already know the port number, it will probably suffice to send a software termination signal to the process (SIGTERM):

```
kill $(lsof -t -i :PORT_NUMBER)
```

Comment: If you know the port is using IPv4 you can do an `lsof -nt -i4TCP:9001` as well.

Comment: I had to do kill -9 $(lsof -t -i :PORT_NUMBER)

Comment: Thank you, so much overkill in other answers. Literally just need this scripted

Comment: The term 'lsof' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file

Answer (score 46):

For use in command line:

```
for /f "tokens=5" %a in ('netstat -aon ^| find ":8080" ^| find "LISTENING"') do taskkill /f /pid %a
```

For use in bat-file:

```
for /f "tokens=5" %%a in ('netstat -aon ^| find ":8080" ^| find "LISTENING"') do taskkill /f /pid %%a
```

Comment: If you want to do it in a .bat, replace %a for %%a

Comment: This answer was the only one line command to work for me so it's really good. I have a task running on two ports which cause the error "ERROR: The process "6552" not found." because the task has already been exited.

Comment: Need really far scroll down to get a **"programmatic"** answer like this. BTw what is `tokens=5`?

Comment: a one-line solution that can be used in package.json scrripts without manual steps

Answer (score 42):

Simple CMD is working me. Easy to remember

find the port number which you want kill and run the below cmd

```
npx kill-port 8080
```

After complete the Port get stopped and getting this message

```
npx: installed 3 in 13.796s
Process on port 8080 killed
```

Answer (score 34):

In **Windows PowerShell** version 1 or later to stop a process on port 3000 type:

> Stop-Process (,(netstat -ano | findstr :3000).split() | foreach {$*[$*.length-1]}) -Force

---

As suggested by @morganpdx here`s a more PowerShell-ish, better version:

> Stop-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 3000).OwningProcess -Force

Comment: `'Stop-Process' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`

Comment: I find that this works: `Stop-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 3000).OwningProcess -Force`

Comment: I get the error: "Get-NetTCPConnection : No MSFT_NetTCPConnection objects found with property 'LocalPort' equal to '49610'.  Verify the
value of the property and retry." However, IIS Express is complaining about this port not being available.

Answer (score 23):

Open command prompt and issue below command

```
netstat -ano|findstr "PID :8888"
```

Output will show the process id occupying the port

[image]

Issue below command to kill the PID

```
taskkill /pid 8912 /f
```

You will receive the output as below

```
SUCCESS: The process with PID 8860 has been terminated.
```

Comment: Works perfectly on newer versions of Powershell too!

Answer (score 20):

If you can use PowerShell on Windows you just need :

```
Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort "8080").OwningProcess | Stop-Process
```

Comment: I like this one-liner (even though it throws ugly messages when there is NO matching process)!

Comment: yes, you are right, but I think I have used when a port is blocked so I never tested the case when there is no matching process! anyway good point :)

Answer (score 17):

For Windows users, you can use the [CurrPorts](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html#DownloadLinks) tool to kill ports under usage easily:

[image]

Comment: No need for CurrPorts. In windows 10+ you can use the Resource Monitor, more precisely its Network Tab. In the bottom pane, there is a section listing all the opened ports and the PID of the processes which are using these ports.

Answer (score 11):

I was running zookeeper on Windows and wasn't able to stop [ZooKeeper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_ZooKeeper) running at 2181 port using zookeeper-stop.sh, so tried this double slash "//" method to taskkill. It worked

```
     1. netstat -ano | findstr :2181
       TCP    0.0.0.0:2181           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       8876
       TCP    [::]:2181              [::]:0                 LISTENING       8876

     2.taskkill //PID 8876 //F
       SUCCESS: The process with PID 8876 has been terminated.
```

Answer (score 11):

### Let's Automate!

If you fall into this issue much often like me, make an .bat file and run it to end process.

### create a bat file "killport.bat"

```
set /P port="Enter port : "
echo showing process running with port %port%

netstat -ano|findstr "PID :%port%"

set /P pid="Enter PID to kill : "

taskkill /pid %pid% /f

set /P exit="Press any key to exit..."
```

Run this file by double clicking and

1. Enter port number (then it will list process with PID)
2. Enter PID to kill

Done

## (Optional)

Set to path environment so that you can access this file from anywhere.

Most probably you will know how to add an new path to env. But here's how if you don't

### Step 1 of 4

Search ENV on start menu

[image]

### Step 2 of 4

Select Environment Variables

[image]

### Step 3 of 4

Select 'path' and click Edit button

[image]

### Step 4 of 4

Click 'New' add the path where .bat file is stored. Since I saved it on '../Documents/bats' folder I am adding this path. Your path will depend on where you save this file.

[image]

#### Open CMD and test. Remember you filename will the word to run this file. Since I saved the .bat file as 'killport.bat' => 'killport' is the word to run it.

[image]
if do enjoy!
else share how you done it here

Answer (score 11):

Run cmd as administrator. Then type this code in there.

```
netstat -ano | findstr :<8080>
```

Then you can see the PID run on your port. Then copy that PID number. ( PID is a unique number that helps identify a hardware product or a registered software product.)  And type below code line and press enter.

```
taskkill /PID <Enter the copied PID Number> /F
```

Answer (score 9):

If you're using [Windows Terminal](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-terminal-1-0/) then the killing process might be little less tedious.
I've been using windows terminal and `kill PID` works fine for me to kill processes on the port as the new Windows Terminal supports certain bash commands. For example: `kill 13300`

So, the complete process will look like this-

- Open Windows Terminal
- Type the following command to show processes running on the port you're looking to kill processes.
  `netstat -ano | findstr :PORT`
- Type following to kill the process.
  `kill PID`

For Example:

```
PS C:\Users\username> netstat -ano | findstr :4445
  TCP    0.0.0.0:4445           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       7368
  TCP    [::]:4445              [::]:0                 LISTENING       7368
PS C:\Users\username> kill 7368
PS C:\Users\username> netstat -ano | findstr :4445
PS C:\Users\username>
```

See when I typed the first command to list processes on the port it returned empty. That means all processes are killed now.

Update: `kill` is an alias for [Stop-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-process?view=powershell-7.1). Thanks, @FSCKur for letting us know.

Comment: I know this works because I tested it, I'm trying to find documentation around it, do you have any?

Comment: @DanStarns, I've found only this so far! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/

Comment: Thanks for your time, it's not quite the page I'm looking for, a page with all the functions provided in the terminal such as `kill`. Ill post here if i find.

Comment: I haven't found much about this as of now. Please post if you find anything.

Comment: I have to downvote because of your confusion about `kill`.  It's NOTHING to do with your choice of terminal. As any fool knows, in PS you use Get-Command to understand what command you're running, and it shows you that, on Windows, kill is an alias for Stop-Process. On Linux it's not an alias but the native command.

Comment: @FSCKur, I don't think it was already there earlier(talking about alias)! It's something new that I found.
Thanks for letting me know about the alias thing. I'll mention this thing in the answer.

Comment: Appreciated; sorry about my previous sharp tone. However, there's still confusion between terminal and shell. You have provided a Powershell answer. A user running bash in WT wouldn't get the same results. If you change "WT" to "PS" then your answer becomes correct... however, it's a PS community guideline to not use aliases in code or help, so I'd still not be happy.

Answer (score 8):

If you use powershell 7+ this worked for me. Just add this function in your $PROFILE file.

```
function killport([parameter(mandatory)] [string] $uport){
    if($upid = (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort $uport -ErrorAction Ignore).OwningProcess){kill $upid}
}
```

then simply use `killport 8080`

or if you prefer just the command you can try this:

```
kill $(Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 8761 -ErrorAction Ignore).OwningProcess
```

Comment: Where is the $PROFILE file?

Comment: You can always find it using the `echo $PROFILE` command. You can also use `notepad $PROFILE` to directly open it in notepad

Comment: @Cos $PROFILE is something similar to .bashrc or .bash_profile in Linux/Unix.

Comment: I didn't try adding to the $PROFILE, but this script also works on PowerShell 5.1

Answer (score 6):

You can do by run a bat file:

```
@ECHO OFF                                                                              
FOR /F "tokens=5" %%T IN ('netstat -a -n -o ^| findstr "9797" ') DO (
SET /A ProcessId=%%T) &GOTO SkipLine                                                   
:SkipLine                                                                              
echo ProcessId to kill = %ProcessId%
taskkill /f /pid %ProcessId%
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 4):

In case you want to do it using Python: check *[Is it possible in python to kill process that is listening on specific port, for example 8080?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20691258/is-possible-in-python-kill-process-which-is-running-on-specific-port-for-exampl)*

The answer from [Smunk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/905256/smunk) works nicely. I repeat his code here:

```
from psutil import process_iter
from signal import SIGTERM # or SIGKILL

for proc in process_iter():
    for conns in proc.connections(kind='inet'):
        if conns.laddr.port == 8080:
            proc.send_signal(SIGTERM) # or SIGKILL
            continue
```

Comment: This worked for a socket that uses a particular port number in Google Cloud as well!
Thanks a ton

Answer (score 3):

the first step

```
netstat -vanp tcp | grep 8888
```

example

```
tcp4     0      0    127.0.0.1.8888   *.*    LISTEN      131072 131072  76061    0
tcp46    0      0    *.8888           *.*    LISTEN      131072 131072  50523    0
```

the second step: find your PIDs and kill them

in my case

```
sudo kill -9 76061 50523
```

Comment: Even if this is a correct answer. The question was asked for windows environment and your answer is invalid on a Linux system.

Answer (score 3):

```
netstat -ano | findstr :PORT
kill PI
```

Answer (score 2):

One line solution using **GitBash**:

```
 tskill `netstat -ano | grep LISTENING | findstr :8080 | sed -r 's/(\s+[^\s]+){4}(.*)/\1/'`
```

Replace **8080** with the port your server is listening to.

If you need to use it often, try adding to your `~/.bashrc` the function:

```
function killport() {
        tskill `netstat -ano | findstr LISTENING | findstr :$1 | sed -r 's/^(\s+[^\s]+){4}(\d*)$/\1/'`
}
```

and simply run

```
killport 8080
```

Comment: I got the error: ```bash: taskill: command not found```

Comment: @ChauGiang It seems a typo. Use `tskill` instead of `taskill`.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a tiny node js script for this. Just run it like this:
`node killPort.js 8080` or whatever port you need to kill. Save the following to a `killPort.js` file:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const fs = require(`fs`);

const port = process.argv.length > 2 ? process.argv[2] : ``;
if (!port || isNaN(port)) console.log(`port is required as an argument and has to be a number`);
else {
    exec(`netstat -ano | findstr :${port}`, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (!stdout) console.log(`nobody listens on port ${port}`);
        else {
            const res = stdout.split(`\n`).map(s => s.trim());
            const pid = res.map(s => s.split(` `).pop()).filter(s => s).pop();
            console.log(`Listener of ${port} is found, its pid is ${pid}, killing it...`);
            exec(`taskkill /PID ${pid} /F`, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
                if (!stdout) console.log(`we tried to kill it, but not sure about the result, please run me again`);
                else console.log(stdout);
            })
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: are you using Mac?

Answer (score 1):

I am using GitBash and I error like below when ran

> taskkill //PID XXXX
>
> ERROR: The process with PID 7420 could not be terminated. Reason: This
> process can only be terminated forcefully (with /F option).

So used //F like below and worked fine

> taskkill //F //PID  XXXX

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script to do it in WSL2

```
PIDS=$(cmd.exe /c netstat -ano | cmd.exe /c findstr :$1 | awk '{print $5}')
for pid in $PIDS
do
    cmd.exe /c taskkill /PID $pid /F
done
```

Answer (score -3):

We can avoid this by simple restarting IIS, using the below command:

```
IISRESET
```