# Python Redis Multiprocessing - redis.exceptions.ConnectionError -

Tags: redis, redis-py, python-3.9

I have written a program that does multiprocessing and does Scan, Get, and Set to Redis. The reason we went with Redis is to speed it up.

Does anybody have any recommendations.  I tried putting a retry loop around the get statements (and can do that for set as well), but the Scan statements will be more tricky.  And is there some parameter I scan change or increase to avoid this?

Error:

```
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 10048 connecting to 192.168.5.51:6379. Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
  File "C:\Apps\ProcessData\redis\connection.py", line 1192, in get_connection
    connection.connect()
  File "C:\Apps\ProcessData\redis\connection.py", line 563, in connect
    raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
  File "C:\Apps\ProcessData\redis\connection.py", line 563, in connect
    raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
```

I think part two of the error was this: waiting for it to happen again to get the exact text:

```
Error 10048 connecting to 192.168.5.51:6379. Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
```

For the code that does a redis-get, I am trying the following:

```
redis_max_retries = 72
redis_retries = 0
redis_get_success = False
sleep_time_in_seconds = .1
while not redis_get_success and redis_retries < redis_max_retries:
    try:
       json_str = redis_obj.get(redis_key)
       redis_get_success = True
    except redis.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        redis_retries += 1
        time.sleep(sleep_time_in_seconds)

if not redis_get_success:
    print("redis_retries=", redis_retries, " on json_str = redis_obj.get(redis_key) in process_intervals" )
    sys.exit(0)
```

But I also get the error on a scan, which look trickier to retry.

```
    for keybatch in batcher(redis_obj.scan_iter(key_pattern), 1500):
        batch_counter += 1
        # print(batch_counter, "keybatch=", keybatch)

        for key in keybatch:
            if key is not None:
                #print("Trying key=", key)
                matching_keys_found += 1
                etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect to online Redis hosting site like [RedisLabs.com](https://redislabs.com) and connect using [documentation](https://redislabs.com/lp/python-redis/) or you can try changing the port.
Error is either arising from port or misconfigured Redis server setup.
Also for the same port and address see [Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41836209/only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-protocol-network-address-port-is-normall)

Comment: We moved to self-hosted Redis because of the memory we needed. It also happens in other programs, so not related to multiprocessing.  Still trying to figure out if my retry works, maybe I need to increase retry time. 
I was just reading this: https://help.socketlabs.com/docs/how-to-fix-error-only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-protocolnetwork-addressport-is-normally-permitted

Comment: I think I saw that post, but we are hosting on Ubuntu, and it didn't mention Redis at all.  Was hoping that redis_py library might solve, since I'm not coding any sockets directly.  But maybe we do need to open some more sockets/ports on that server...
Also it normally works fine when running one Python program at a time, or no multiprocessing.  So it's not a documentation/port issue.  I am able to connect, I think I'm out of connections.

Comment: Try using connection_pool property and disconnect on completion. This might pave way for more connections. Unless it is important to have more than one connections simultaneously.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://redis.io/topics/clients