# MySQL Error: Cannot connect. Invalid Settings When adding data via for loop

Tags: python, mysql

I am using `mysql.connector` library to connect to the MySQL database. Whenever I loop through my dictionary and add data to the database, I get the following error after a few successful insertions of records into the database.

[Mysql error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atYhm.png)

Is it the right way to way to loop and add data to the database?

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and the error message, both in text form

Comment: You may want to check this post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41836612/7510829

Comment: @NicoHaase `import mysql.connector 
conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", database="dbtest")
cursor = conn.cursor()
for kwl, count_of_proj in myDict:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbtest(kw,count) VALUES(%s, %s)", 
    (kwl,count_of_proj))
conn.commit()
conn.close()`

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. This should also contain the error message