# Unhandled exception 0xE0434352 does not get wrapped into a .NET Exception

Tags: c#, c++, .net, crash, com

Here's my scenario:

- .NET 6.0.11
- Native application, running as a Windows service, calls a .NET 6 assembly via a .NET generated .comhost.dll using COM
- The .NET assembly blocks on System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive call

**When shutting down the OS**, the Receive call gets an unhandled exception:

`Unhandled exception at 0x77438642 (KERNELBASE.dll) in myapp.exe.3180.dmp: 0xE0434352 (parameters: 0x80004005, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x71370000).`

The try/catch block cannot handle the exception, i.e. it seems the exception isn't wrapped into a .NET Exception and the catch block below isn't hit:

```cs
try
{
    return s.Receive(buffer); // <- the unhandled exception seen in a crash dump
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Trace($"Receive error - ex: {ex}");
    throw;
}
```

This unhandled exception does not result in a HRESULT being returned to the native code and the process crashes. A registered `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` does not get triggered.

When the OS runs normally, the internal Receive exceptions are properly wrapped into an Exception, the catch block is hit and a HRESULT is returned to the native code.

I'm colleting the crash dump with WER. This crash gets also logged as Informational in the Application Windows Logs:

```
Fault bucket 1695090666501866404, type 1
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: myapp.exe
P2: 1.0.0.0
P3: 63984a64
P4: KERNELBASE.dll
P5: 10.0.20348.1249
P6: ac7a852c
P7: e0434352
P8: 00138642
P9: 
P10:
```

The native stack for the exception is:

```
    KERNELBASE.dll!_RaiseException@16() Unknown
    coreclr.dll!RaiseTheExceptionInternalOnly(Object * throwable, int rethrow=0x00000000, int) Line 2807    C++
    coreclr.dll!IL_Throw(Object * obj=0x021463a0) Line 4119 C++
    System.Net.Sockets.dll!6fb66362()   Unknown
    [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, native debugger attempting to walk managed call stack]   
    073689cd()  Unknown
    07368801()  Unknown
    0736843d()  Unknown
    073682c8()  Unknown
    coreclr.dll!@COMToCLRDispatchHelper@32()    Unknown
    coreclr.dll!InvokeStub(ComCallMethodDesc * pCMD, unsigned long pManagedTarget=0x021463a0, Object * orThis=0x0213efac, ComMethodFrame * pFrame=0x0191eea8, Thread * pThread=0x00b96d40, unsigned __int64 * pRetValOut=0x0191ee88) Line 197   C++
    [Inline Frame] coreclr.dll!COMToCLRInvokeTarget(unsigned long) Line 342 C++
    [Inline Frame] coreclr.dll!COMToCLRWorkerBody(Thread *) Line 457    C++
    coreclr.dll!COMToCLRWorker(Thread * pThread=0x00b96d40, ComMethodFrame * pFrame=0x0191eea8) Line 560    C++
    01d0d359()  Unknown
    .. the rest of the stack in myapp.exe ...
```

And the managed stack is:

```
    KERNELBASE.dll!_RaiseException@16() Unknown
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Net.Sockets.dll!System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(System.Span<byte> buffer) Line 1495    C#
    .. the rest of the stack in myapp.exe ..
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to proceed with debugging this?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe there is something more helpful in the eventlogs "Net Runtime" section.

Comment: @Ralf thanks but there's just this Informational APPCRASH logged by Windows Error Reporting and no "Net Runtime" entries.

Comment: Have you registered a [preshutdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/service-control-handler-function) notification? If the crash occured after that, it's your duty to close the .net app when OS is shutting down.

Comment: Thank you @shingo, there's preshutdown registered. Do you mean I need to close the Socket in a response to the preshutdown?

Comment: Yes, if the crash is caused by shutdown of other services, you can stop it from happening. It looks like the CLR just doesn't want to catch this exception, check the comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/c81e7a216a3f3c65ae2803381815861d846a7a74/src/coreclr/vm/jithelpers.cpp#L3969

Comment: I'll give it a try @shingo and let you know how it goes in case you'd like to add your solution as an answer here.

Comment: Hi @shingo. Closing the socket in the preshutdown handler fixes the problem for me, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

based on your logs it is highly likely that the application is trying to use a port that is already in use. try identifying the port that is in use and then kill the process, then try your process once again. I started seeing a similar behavior in Win2016, it was not happening in Win2008 R2 nor Win2012. Below some useful links I used to troubleshoot on Win2016.

[Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41836209/only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-protocol-network-address-port-is-normall)

https://help.socketlabs.com/docs/how-to-fix-error-only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-protocolnetwork-addressport-is-normally-permitted