# 500 Internal Server Error for URL: http://localhost:8100/api/timeline

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

**500 Internal Server Error for URL:http://localhost:8100/api/timeline**    *dev4living/HeyCommunity*

> I am trying to run a dev4living/HeyCommunity webApp on a local host but i'm getting the following error:
>
> Error: connect EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:8100
>   at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
>   at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20)
>   at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1087:14)

[http://localhost:8100/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5D3D.png)

-i used the lastest update dev-playing : dev4living/HeyCommunity-backend and dev4living/HeyCommunity-frontendenter code here

-What should i do to fix this error?
-Your assistance will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The error states that the port you are trying to use is already occupied. Please check the app running in the port 8100 and stop that and try to run the app again. Changing the port number to something else apart from 8100 will also solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty self-explanatory buddy. It just means that the address you have used, i.e, the port number is currently in use by something else.

2 possible solutions:

1. Simply change the port number
2. using cmd to get the list of processes running. Identify the process running on that port. And use taskkill -pid command. [Refer this stack overflow post for details regarding this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632667/how-to-kill-the-process-currently-using-a-port-on-localhost-in-windows)