# Cannot stop ZooKeeper in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, apache-zookeeper

When I tried to stop the ZooKeeper with command "`zkServer stop`", I got the following result:

```
call "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121"\bin\java "-Dzookeeper.log.dir=C:\zookeeper-3.4.10\bin\.." "-Dzookeeper.root.logger=INFO,CONSOLE" -cp "C:\zookeeper-3.4.10\bin\..\build\classes;C:\zookeeper-3.4.10\bin\..\build\lib\*;C:\zookeeper-3.4.10\bin\..\*;C:\zookeeper-3.4.10\bin\..\lib\*;C:\zookeeper-3.4.10\bin\..\conf" org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain "C:\zookeeper-3.4.10\bin\..\conf\zoo.cfg" stop
```

Output:

```
2017-09-01 13:55:22,070 [myid:] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@78] - autopurge.snapRetainCount set to 3
2017-09-01 13:55:22,072 [myid:] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@79] - autopurge.purgeInterval set to 0
2017-09-01 13:55:22,072 [myid:] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@101] - Purge task is not scheduled.
2017-09-01 13:55:22,072 [myid:] - WARN  [main:QuorumPeerMain@113] - Either no config or no quorum defined in config, running  in standalone mode
2017-09-01 13:55:22,145 [myid:] - ERROR [main:ZooKeeperServerMain@55] - Invalid arguments, exiting abnormally
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "C:\zookeeper-3.4.10\bin\..\conf\zoo.cfg"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerConfig.parse(ServerConfig.java:59)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.initializeAndRun(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:84)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.main(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:53)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:116)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:78)
2017-09-01 13:55:22,148 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServerMain@56] - Usage: ZooKeeperServerMain configfile | port datadir [ticktime] [maxcnxns]
```

I am sure I have started the Zookeeper, because when I tried to start a new one, it shows "`java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind`"

Another strange problem is that I cannot find Zookeeper in the Windows Service list. However, when I tried to show all port usage in Windows PowerShell by `netstat -and`, I found the 2181 is in use:

```
 Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
 TCP    0.0.0.0:2181           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
[java.exe]
 TCP    [::1]:2181             [::1]:62268            ESTABLISHED
[java.exe]
 TCP    [::1]:2181             [::1]:62279            ESTABLISHED
[java.exe]
 TCP    [::1]:2181             [::1]:62280            ESTABLISHED
[java.exe]
 TCP    [::1]:2181             [::1]:62281            ESTABLISHED
[java.exe]
```

Comment: What is the command that you've used to start it?

Comment: @user10089632  just ".\bin\zkServer", but I also tried ".\bin\zkServer .\conf\zoo.cfg"

Comment: Very well, then try to `kill` it as an admin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there is an [open bug concerning the start and stop commands in ZooKeeper](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-1122)

- To start ZooKeeper, omit the `start` parameter and call `bin\zkServer` instead.
- To stop it, if you don't see the process from the task manager. You need to connect to ZooKeeper server as an administrator and perform the `kill` commands.
  More [details are here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632667/how-to-kill-a-currently-using-port-on-localhost-in-windows).

Comment: Yeah, thank you! And I killed it by "netstat -ano | findstr :2181" and "taskkill /PID typeyourPIDhere /F". See details at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632667/how-to-kill-a-currently-using-port-on-localhost-in-windows

Comment: I'll add that, to be a more complete answer

Answer (score 4):

I was running ZooKeeper on Windows and wasn't able to stop ZooKeeper running at 2181 port using zookeeper-stop.sh, so I tried this double slash "//" method to taskkill. It worked

```
1. netstat -ano | findstr :2181

  TCP    0.0.0.0:2181           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       8876
  TCP    [::]:2181              [::]:0                 LISTENING       8876

2. taskkill //PID 8876 //F

  SUCCESS: The process with PID 8876 has been terminated.
```

Credit goes to: *[How do I kill the process currently using a port on localhost in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632667/how-to-kill-the-process-currently-using-a-port-on-localhost-in-windows)*