# Flask - Webserver not reloading on code change

Tags: python, flask, port

For some reason, 127.0.0.1:5000(port 5000) is stuck displaying my old un-updated file.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Home page"

@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return "About page"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I changed the port and it worked fine.
But, why is 5000 not updating when I change and run my code?
I checked to see if multiple process were running, but none were.

Honestly, this is a noob question, but I can't seem to find anyone else who's had this problem.

Comment: ... you have another flask running somewhere...

Comment: What do you see if you run these commands: `$ telnet localhost 5000` and `$ ps aux | grep 5000`

Comment: Thank you, but I actually resolved the issue. Yes, it was running somewhere. I `statnet -a -b` in command and found python was still listening on port 5000. So, I just ended the task. Now, my question is, how was it still listening if I manually decide when to run and end the server?

Comment: @BryanHinchliffe, I know this is quite old but I am having the same issue. How did you manage to solve the issue? I am working in a windows computer and Pycharm. Thanks

Comment: @Ana Sorry for the late response. I'm assuming you resolved this issue by now, but if it helps, I had to manually kill the Python process running on port 5000. You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632667/how-do-i-kill-the-process-currently-using-a-port-on-localhost-in-windows) answer (option 2) to find and kill process. Hope this helps!

Comment: @BryanHinchliffe. Thanks. I resolved this by disconnected the computer, and stopped running everything. I tried all the answers in the post but none worked.

Answer (score 15):

Press CTR + C to end your server on the terminal and copy and paste this in the terminal to run Flask again

```
export FLASK_DEBUG=1 && flask run
```

This will set Debug mode: on

Comment: The term 'FLASK_DEBUG=1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Comment: fixed issue with not recognized name

Answer (score 8):

To set variable in powershell -

```
$env:FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

Answer (score 7):

No! You have not run your app in **debug mode**.

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

This way any changes in your code will restart the server and your code changes will reflect pretty much in real time.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why this happens. Other answer didn't help. Community should help.

**Other Two options:**

1. If you are using Visual Studio Code, Close and Open it.
2. Uninstall and install python again.

Comment: Restarting VSCode worked for me, thank you!

Comment: I had the same problem, I am using sublime text, closing and opening it worked thx!

Answer (score 3):

To anyone still struggling with this issue while having `debug=True` correctly passed to `app.run()`, Flask (2.0.x) documentation states that :

> debug=True can be passed to enable the debugger and reloader, but the FLASK_ENV=development environment variable is still required to fully enable development mode

See https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/server/

So you should also run your development server with `export FLASK_ENV=development` before `flask run`.

Answer (score 3):

flask --app <.py file name> --debug run

Answer (score 1):

Reload the page using Shift+ F5. But make sure app should be in debug mode i.e. **app.run(debug=True)**.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that another application (Proton Mail Bridge) was listening on the same port (5000) my Flask app was, however no error was thrown. If you are on Windows, I would try running `netstat -ab` in CMD after opening as an administrator and see if any applications are listening to the same port your flask app is running on.

4.5 years later I know, but I could not find any answers on this earlier.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the built-in **app.run()** try adding **app.run(debug=True)**
It solves.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the Flask server froze. For me the solution was to kill the `pythonw.exe` process in the task manager.

Answer (score 0):

For me, running these three commands took care of the reloading problem (windows machine):

```
$env:FLASK_APP = "main.py"
$env:FLASK_DEBUG = 1
flask run
```