# Node.js port connection

Tags: node.js

I have a problem when trying to open a Node.js app on port 3000 because I have another app running(i don't know how because I tried to relaunch my laptop over and over again). How can I close the connection on port 3000 or close that app?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: windows operating

Comment: Can you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632667/how-to-kill-a-currently-using-port-on-localhost-in-windows