# Eclipse closed automatically

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

When I was running my project on 8080 port immediately the eclipse closed automatically and the port is still running with the project, I reponed and I can't run the project on 8080 port anymore.

In Mac OS.

Comment: You need to kill any apps running on that port first then you can reopen eclipse and run the project again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632667/how-to-kill-a-currently-using-port-on-localhost-in-windows

Comment: How about in Mac OS?

Comment: `lsof -i :8080` then `kill <pid>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[sudo] lsof -ti:8080 | xargs kill` should pull up the PID binding to 8080 and kill it