# Browser-sync error on all projects after reinstalling Windows

Tags: npm, gulp, browser-sync

After reinstalling Windows 10, I get the following error upon launching `gulp watch`:

`Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000 at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11) ... at module.exports.plugin (D:\xampp\htdocs\blagnac\wp-content\themes\blagnac\gulp\node_modules\browser-sync\dist\server\index.js:27:25)`

[image]

I tried `npm install browser-sync --save-dev`, I tried `npm install`, and I tried `npm rebuild`. Nothing works. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that there is already a process running in port 3000.

**Option 1 (preferred)**

In order to run gulp watch on port 3000, you need to kill the existing process that is running on port 3000. 
The steps for killing a process are given in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632667/how-to-kill-a-currently-using-port-on-localhost-in-windows).

**Option 2**

An alternative would be change the port in which gulp runs from 3000 to something else say 3001.