# IntelliJ / WebStorm - Terminate vs Disconnect

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, webstorm

Running a node.js process (not sure it is relevant).

When I stop a process I get the following dialog:

[image]

What is the difference between Terminate and Disconnect?

Comment: Generally speaking ... "Disconnect" means that process will keep running but the debugger (or whatever was attached to it) will be disconnected. "Terminate" will end the process. I doubt that it has other special meaning here...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Terminate** causes the running process(es) to stop; **Disconnect** keeps the process running, but the IDE (debugger, etc.) will no more be attached to it. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2018.2/system-settings.html, *On Closing Tool Windows with Running Process*

Comment: I started a serverSocket on a port, and then used "Disconnect". Now, I cannot connect to that port anymore since it is hogged. How do I fix this? `java.net.BindException: Address already in use: NET_Bind`. Another Exception I get comes from my "finally" (in try-catch-finally where I opened the socket that fails to open) that was supposed to make sure the socket gets closed: `serverSocket.close();` returns this Exception: `Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Comment: Terminate your server socket. You can't connect to a running socket by re-starting it.

Comment: Indeed, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39633428/9768291) helped me do such a thing.

Comment: Is it any way to "Connect" to the process again?

Comment: no way to do this