# How to stop the Django development server on windows

Tags: django, windows

I found here answers how to stop the Django Server on Linux but not on windows.

Do I really need to restart my machine ?

Comment: Where you run your server? cmd or powershell? Is it says "The port already in use."

Comment: no, I'm run it from Pycharm terminal, so I presume cmd; If I close a project in Pycharm and forget to close the server, it remains open; if I start again a project the initial server is seen, and now way to close it; to use a different server

Comment: If you try to re run the project then what will see?

Comment: the initial server, if I make change in code nothing happens

Comment: Try to kill the port the server already run then run the server again. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632667/how-to-kill-the-process-currently-using-a-port-on-localhost-in-windows/55218770#55218770

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Open Resource Monitor in the Command Prompt using the command resmon.
- At the "Listening Ports", find the port you're using.
  [image: See Resource Monitor here.]
- In my case, is Port 8000.
- Get the PID, in this example is 20132.
- Open Task Manager, go to Tab Details, find the PID and end the task.

[image: See Task Manager here]

Answer (score 8):

In your terminal, spam <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> a few times.

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for a programmatic solution, closing `port 8000` and all associated connections (there may be more than one) can be done with a `.bat` script:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /A port=8000
FOR /F "tokens=5" %%T IN ('netstat -ano ^| findstr :%port%') DO (
    SET /A processid=%%T
    TASKKILL /PID %%T /F
)
```

Note that the `CMD` line `netstat -ano ^| findstr :%port%` is used to list the connections using `port 8000`:

````
  >netstat -ano | findstr :8000
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       10920
  TCP    10.0.1.11:8000         10.0.1.11:14813        ESTABLISHED     10920
  TCP    10.0.1.11:8000         10.0.1.11:14814        ESTABLISHED     10920
  TCP    10.0.1.11:8000         10.0.1.11:14815        ESTABLISHED     10920
  TCP    10.0.1.11:14813        10.0.1.11:8000         ESTABLISHED     2628
  TCP    10.0.1.11:14814        10.0.1.11:8000         ESTABLISHED     2628
  TCP    10.0.1.11:14815        10.0.1.11:8000         ESTABLISHED     2628```
````

Answer (score 0):

Edit1:
On windows I used 'Run manage.py Task' in pycharm and I simply closed pycharm and the port is not in use anymore

Edit2: If you are using 'Run manage.py Task' in pycharm, check this:
[My picture of terminating server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbGn4.png)
There's a in-built option for stopping the server in pycharm

Answer (score 0):

Just Press ctr+C instead of CTRL+BREAK  (There is no BREAK key present on keyboard) . [To fix unapplied migration I wanted to quit server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAdG2.png)