# Webpack watch not allowing to listen on open port?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-watch

I've been following a guide to learn wepback and its bundling capabilities and wanted to find a way to automatically update the browser when a change was made to the code and found that --watch is one way to do so.

Without any watch in the webpack.config.json file or in the package.json file, the site is compiled correctly and says "Listening on port 8080"

When I add --watch to the package.json build script and watch/watchOptions to the webpack.config.json file I get the issue where it just hangs and doesn't print "Listening on port 8080"

Here is my code:

**webpack.config.json**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const outputDirectory = 'dist';

console.log(__dirname);
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'bundle.js': [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/index.js'),
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name]',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  // entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/client/index.js'],
  // output: {
  //   path: path.join(__dirname, outputDirectory),
  //   filename: 'bundle.js'
  // },

  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },

  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    open: true,
    inline: true,
    proxy: {
      '/api': 'http://localhost:8080'
    }
  },
  watch: true,
  watchOptions: {
    poll: true,
    ignored: /node_modules/
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin([outputDirectory]),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html',
      favicon: './public/favicon.ico'
    })
  ]
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "simple-react-full-stack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Boilerplate to build a full stack web application using React, Node.js, Express and Webpack.",
  "main": "src/server/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production --watch --colors",
    "start": "npm run build && node src/server/index.js",
    "client": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --devtool inline-source-map --hot",
    "server": "nodemon src/server/index.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
  "author": "Sandeep Raveesh",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "eslint": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.7.0",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.3"
  }
```

Here is an image of what the command line shows me after doing npm start
[git command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jq1ld.png)

Help is greatly appreciated, this is the only thing I am stuck on and afterwards i am smooth sailing for Node.js and React.js :)

Answer (score 0):

```
"webpack-cli": "3.3.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "3.1.3"
```

try removing the cap symbol and give npm install

you need to run webpack-dev-server with the --hot flag:

webpack-dev-server --content-base ./ --port 9966 --hot

Then you can access the hot-loading version localhost:9966/webpack-dev-server/

You don't need to run watch as well.

update:
This entry in your webpack config must change:

entry: ['./js/main.js'], --> entry: ['webpack/hot/dev-server' , './js/main.js']

Change your publicPath entry:

publicPath: '/assets/'

Comment: I just tried that out and I get the same thing, the wepback bundles all files, but doesnt open up port for listening...

Comment: what it's exactly saying?try previous version of webpack

Comment: Attached to the post is a link to an image of what the command line is saying

Comment: It seems to just hang, im really not sure

Comment: ok cool.kill the port and try again 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632667/how-to-kill-the-process-currently-using-a-port-on-localhost-in-windows

Comment: Solution was to include a middleware since im using proxy in my webpack config.

Answer (score 0):

Use webpack-hot-middleware, links here: https://blog.cloudboost.io/live-reload-hot-module-replacement-with-webpack-middleware-d0a10a86fc80

and

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-hot-middleware