# How to end server in VSCode after closing terminal window

Tags: node.js, powershell, visual-studio-code

I'm sure some of us have at least done it once when working with full-stack and VS Code, we leave the server running without stopping the batch process with ^C. Then when we want to run the code after updates we have to jump through hoops like signing out or else just face the `Port XXXX is already in use`.

What is the most efficient way to end a process from the cmd/powershell/node terminal **inside VS Code**?

For a scenario:

`node server.js` which initializes a server listener on `localhost:3000`, but then I close the terminal window accidentally, what is a command to enter in a new terminal that can act the same as ^C in the old terminal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to kill the process currently using a port on localhost in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632667/how-to-kill-the-process-currently-using-a-port-on-localhost-in-windows)

Comment: I did look at that, I was wondering if there was something more specific for VS Code @ManuelSpigolon

Comment: I dont think there is anything more specific on VSCode explicitly. However, the link provided by @ManuelSpigolon is well versed and fits your need.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I do this all time. If you write 'npx kill-port 3000' it should do the trick.