# Kill windows process that keeps restarting

Tags: node.js, web-services, process, port

**I am trying to stop a windows service that is using a port I need, but the service keeps restarting it self. How do I stop it from restarting itself?**

I followed this question to kill it ([How to kill the process currently using a port on localhost in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632667/how-to-kill-the-process-currently-using-a-port-on-localhost-in-windows)), but when I listen for the port again a new service started already:

[image]

How this happened and some notes:

- I created a Nodejs service and started it as a windows service (so now it is running in it's own windows instance)
- My service had a cmd line to stop it self `net stop "Service Name"`. This semi-failed for some reason (it did stop, kinda, but then it starts again)
- I have even uninstalled the Nodejs service completely, but still something is starting it up over and over (because the port stays in use)
- I can't move the Nodejs service files, because they are `in use`

Answer (score 2):

To find out what application/service the PID is referring to, you can open Resource Monitor by running: **resmon**

Then choose CPU tab and look for the PID, Note: it could be under Processes or Services. If it's a service then you can stop and disable it so it won't run again.

If it's a Process, the name should give you an idea what it is.

Comment: This helped me to kill a process that was messing up my system clock (running about 10 minutes slow and would not stay synchronised with internet time - would briefly sync then go back to being slow).