# ECONNREFUSED on running localhost server from NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, localhost, econnrefused

I have a NodeJS server up and running on my local machine that is listening to port 50000.
From another server, that is also running on my local machine, I need to make a simple GET request to that server, but all I get is an ECONNREFUSED error:

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:50000
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1106:14)
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 50000 }
```

My request looks as follows, using `request`:

```
var options = {
    url: "http://localhost:50000",
    method: "GET"
}
request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        console.log("[" + getDateTime() + "] Error connecting to localhost:");
        console.log(error);
        return;
   }
   // continue ...
```

I know that the server is up and running and that the endpoint is defined, because I can do the request to that exact same url in postman or in my browser and get a response, but somehow not in my NodeJS code.

Anybody have an idea?

Comment: Changing `localhost` to `http://127.0.01:50000` worked for me. I guess node wasn't respecting the hosts file on my Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The possible issue is that some else process is already running on the same port you are trying to use, either change your port or kill the existing process on your port. To kill the process on port you can try:

For mac:

```
sudo kill $(lsof -t -i:8000) 
# or 
sudo fuser -k -n tcp 8000 
# or 
fuser -k 8000/tcp
```

And for windows check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632667/how-do-i-kill-the-process-currently-using-a-port-on-localhost-in-windows)

hope this helps :)

Comment: The link for the windows help is broken

Answer (score 12):

Just as commented, changing "localhost" to "http://127.0.0.1:50000" worked for me.
I ll leave a link down here for a possible explanation for this issue

https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/issues/1624#issuecomment-1235826631

Answer (score 5):

Use this at the beginning of your code:

```
const dns = require('dns');

// Set default result order for DNS resolution
dns.setDefaultResultOrder('ipv4first');
```

Comment: I was running into this just now on my Windows machine, found that 127.0.0.1:port did work for me, so I added these lines and now localhost works as well. I think without it, it was coming in as ::1 (IPv6) and my server-side wasn't handling that. But not sure of the actual cause, only that calling setDefaultResultOrder() did in fact fix it to support localhost.

Comment: Thank you Shubham! While running integration tests using h2o2 proxy, I created 'targetServer' Hapi server on a free port, then 'proxyServer' Hapi server on a different port, configured with a proxy definition. I hit proxyServer, which was supposed to proxy to the targetServer, but I'd get ECONNREFUSED every time from the targetServer, despite knowing that targetServer was up, running, and successfully responding on the right path. I spent hours troubleshooting until the above code fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

You might be running both the servers on the same port, kill another server on same port.

If you're on linux, you can kill port using `sudo fuser -k -n tcp 5000`

or if you're using windows:  `taskkill /PID 5000 /F`

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, Nodejs isn't so specific with what's actually causing an error. I received this ECONNREFUSED error message in the context of Firebase Cloud Messaging, trying to send a message. After reading Stack I thought it meant I should setup a proxy situation, but that made no difference bc my connection wasn't really the problem. It was an error in the object I drafted to send which needed editing - after editing the error went away and everything was fine. Bear this in mind: consider how one wrong thing can make another appear to be wrong.