# I'm trying to print Hello World with Spring Boot and want to fix a login window

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Hello? I'm a developer trying to study Spring Boot.
For now, I just wanted to print Hello World on a web page, so I created a controller package and a class.
I will post the entire code first.

First is the `pom.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.limsrs</groupId>
<artifactId>testproject</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>testproject</name>
<description>testproject for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Next is the `TestprojectApplication.java` file.

```java
package com.limsrs.testproject;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestprojectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestprojectApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext context) {
        return args -> {
            System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

            String[] beanNames = context.getBeanDefinitionNames();
            Arrays.sort(beanNames);
            for (String beanName : beanNames) {
                System.out.println(beanName);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Last is the `HelloWorldController.java` file.

```java
package com.limsrs.testproject.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "Hello World~!";
    }
}
```

After running the `spring boot app`, I tried to connect to `localhost: 8080` and the login window appeared.
If you search the Internet, you will see the login method using `spring-security`, but not that, and you will not see the Hello World screen.

What I want to do is simply see the Hello World screen. The login window is not what I want.

Comment: Are you sure Spring Boot not failed to run on localhost:8080 and some other Spring Security application is already running on that port?

Comment: Can you tell me where to check?
First of all, ```spring boot app``` has a project in ```testproject```.
It also includes icons with two gears, such as ```configserver```.

Comment: I did not understand "spring boot app has a project in testproject. It also includes icons with two gears, such as configserver". But when you started your spring boot app, are you getting "Started TestprojectApplication in 3.713 seconds (JVM running for 4.304)" message? Also check the content of src/main/resources/application.properties

Comment: can you try running it on different port? @limsrs

Comment: Looking closely at the message, I found the message ```ERROR 9704 --- [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase: Failed to start component [Connector [HTTP / 1.1-8080]].```

And there is nothing in ```application.properties```.

Comment: I found a way to change the port.

```server.port = 8100``` This will bring up ```Hello World!```
Thank you.

Comment: I was about to say the same. So some other application was running on 8080 and that was configured with Spring Security :-)

Comment: Do you ever know how to delete a running app on 8080?
In sts boot app it is invisible except for my app.

Comment: kill that process running on 8080 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632667/how-to-kill-the-process-currently-using-a-port-on-localhost-in-windows

Comment: you can follow the below steps to close the port https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632667/how-to-kill-the-process-currently-using-a-port-on-localhost-in-windows

Comment: ans also can you add any error messages displayed in console @limsrs

Comment: It says that you can't quit because access is denied.

Comment: Hello, @limsrs can you update the question with an error which you are getting.

Comment: I ended up using Task manager.