# OSError: [WinError 10013] - python

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I'm new in Python and i try to run my website and i get that error : `OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions`

So far i know, python runs on port 5000. When i change the port programmatic like that:

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':
 if platform.system() == "Windows":
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5050, debug=True)
```

To 5050 or any port, it runs.
But i want it to run on port 5000 as the defualt config.
What should i do? how can i fix it? Is it problem with my laptop or with the program?

**Error log:**

[image]

**What should i do now?**

[image]

**Edit - solution**

I have followed this linked 
[How do I kill the process currently using a port on localhost in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632667/how-do-i-kill-the-process-currently-using-a-port-on-localhost-in-windows) , and after i killed the process that was listening to the port 5000, i was able to run the project.

Comment: please post new error if anything pops up

Comment: I have added the error log