# How can I shut down the local firebase emulators?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

Currently I initialise the firebase emulators with:

`$ firebase emulators:start`

After some time working on it I want to stop it. How can I then stop the emulators?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

1. Check which process is occupying the port `sudo lsof -i tcp:<port>`
2. Kill the process `kill -9 <process id>`

Comment: I have found that if you exit VSCode without shutting down the emulators first it can remain running and without the above commands, you will need to restart the computer to be able to restart the emulators.  Thank you for sharing @xmkevinchen

Comment: For windows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39633428/681803

Comment: @ra9r on linux the process is called _java_. If you kill it you won't need to restart your computer.

Comment: I'm flabbergasted there is no shutdown command...this is an insane workflow.

Comment: This seems like such an obvious feature to include in a command `firebase emulators:stop` or similar, it makes me think I'm using the tool wrong.

Is the normal workflow to start up the emulators and leave them running in the background while developing for long periods of time?

Comment: @JeffNeet that's the way I use it. I fire up the function/firestore emulators and work on event functions and db triggers. Sometimes it completely blows out and stops with an error leaving the process running which is when I need the answer below by user kazuwombat. Generally tho, 2x Ctrl-C is enough.

Comment: Using `kill -2` might be better as it will send `SIGINT` instead of `SIGKILL`. It will have the same effect as pressing `Ctrl + C` in the emulator terminal and will allow for a clean shutdown.

Answer (score 31):

according to this: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1367 `Ctrl+C` kills the emulators

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work on a MacBook.

Comment: Not possible if there isn't one visually running.

Comment: Doesn't kill the java console with Ctrl+C in windows also

Comment: It gracefully shuts down on a Mac now; `Ctrl+C` initiates a graceful shutdown that takes about 3 seconds to complete (there's output in the console as it happens). If you press `Ctrl+C` again during the graceful shutdown, then some ports might stay blocked (due to Java keeping them) – in this case, refer to another answer that explains how to release ports.

Answer (score 31):

One cross-platform solution is to just run [kill-port](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kill-port) :

`npx kill-port 4000 8080 8085`

Comment: Faster option, and work in windows and Linux

Comment: The command should be: `npx kill-port 4000 8080 8085`. Spaces between port numbers instead of commas.

Answer (score 26):

If you wanna kill all firebase emulators you can easily do that by firing this command

```
$ lsof -t -i:8080 -i:9000 -i:9099 -i:9199 -i:9090 | xargs kill -9
```

When you don't want to type this long command each time I advise you to use a script in the **package.json** file

```
 "scripts": {
   "emulators:start": "firebase emulators:start",
   "emulators:stop": "lsof -t -i:5001 -i:5002 -i:8080 -i:9000 -i:9099 -i:9199 -i:9090 | xargs kill -9"
  }
```

One for starting your emulators and one for stopping, in case Ctr+C didn't stop the processes in the background.

Those are the default PORTS from the documentation page in firebase. You should also check your **firebase.json** file and replace the PORTS in the previous command if they are different.

Comment: add port 5000 for firebase hosting

Comment: Thanks, there are multiple emulators you can check the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#port_configuration) and add what you need

Comment: where is the package.json file ?

Answer (score 18):

If you don't want to have to check the port every time, you can stop command with below

```
kill -9 (lsof -t -i:5002 -i:5001)
```

(-i:xxxx are your running emulator ports in firebase.json.)

Moreover, I don't want to memorize this long command.
So I made package.json script below.

```
"scripts": {
   ...
   "stop": "lsof -t -i :5001 -i:5002 | xargs kill -9",
   ...
}
```

Comment: Nothing like a little automation to simplify your day.

Answer (score 6):

So here's a bit of fun I just discovered. Double tap CTRL-C (hold down CTRL and double tap C) in the terminal running the emulator when you want to shut down the emulator and clear all the ports and processes.

I've checked it a couple of times and looked to see if the ports are free, they all are.

Just using CTRL-C once leaves you with all those ports still being used. Hope it solves the problem for others and not just me.

Edit: Looks to me now like the problem only persists until first shutdown of the computer after setting up the emulators. I now have no problems with the emulators shutting down properly with a single CTRL-C.

Answer (score 5):

I've tried all the answers above, and none does what I was expecting: to gracefully end the emulator suite as a whole without having to ctrl+c, leaving no ports occupied. Here is how I've solved it.

TLDR: `lsof -ti :4400 | xargs --no-run-if-empty kill`

The port being 4400, as it's the default port for the Emulator Hub. Although with this command you'll end the emulator regardless of the process you kill.

The"-9" flag used in the other answers does not send the SIGTERM signal to the process, but forcefully kills it instead. This prevents the emulator from ending gracefully.

Comment: this was it for me, though --no-run-if-empty is bogus on macOS

Answer (score 5):

An alternative is to use `firebase emulators:exec`, which, according  to the CLI documentation, does this:

> start the local Firebase emulators, run a test script, then shut down the emulators

Since I put my test running command in a Makefile, I use the following command to test firestore from a Python `firebase_admin` SDK:

```
firebase emulators:exec "make test" --only firestore
```

The set-up and tear-down of the port is handled by firebase directly.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way you can stop the emulators:

`pkill -f "firebase/emulators"`

According to the Firebase Emulators SDK documentation ([link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#startup)):

> Calling emulators:start will download the emulators to ~/.cache/firebase/emulators/ if they are not already installed.

So, this solution works because:

- The emulator process is provided a .jar file, located in this directory
- Since this jar path is in the process name, pkill -f can find it by name

This is more robust than solutions that make assumptions about what ports the emulator is running on, and it works if you have multiple instances of a specific emulator running.

Comment: This one works!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Node in your project you can call

```
npx kill-port 3000 8080 9000 5001 5000 9199
```

You can put this into a script in your `package.json` to easily call with `npm run kill`.

```
"scripts": {
  "kill": "npx kill-port 3000 8080 9000 5001 5000 9199"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, first find PID of the process using port 8080 by typing this in cmd.

```
netstat -a -n -o | find "8080"
```

Next, kill that process by:

```
taskkill /PID <type PID here>
```