# flutter app suddenly can't fetch data from firestore, Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I've been searching for a lot of problems that relate to this but I still didn't find the solution
the error says

> Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)

> [WriteStream]: (26986c6) Stream closed with status: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}.

> [Firestore]: Write failed at users/rX5LRztKddW1c8RIBqyNShligJV2: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.

and I've tried to change the firebase firestore rules in my console to be like this

```
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
 match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
  }
 }
}
```

and after that still didn't affect anything. Usually I still can fetch data into a list and show in a gridview without having a user login. but now even when I log the user in it still didn't give me any of the data. been checking my dart code too and didn't find anything suspicious. tried to uninstall and install it back. nope, didnt works too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Resolve the problem by Un-enforced the app check on the firebase console. by doing this

```
 Project Settings > App-Check > APIs > Cloud Firestore click UnEnforce.
```

but in my case it still won't work. and i try to disconnect the flutter app with the firebase console and create a new one without connecting the app-check feature, and it work properly now

Answer (score -1):

Did you try like this

```
allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
```

or

```
 service cloud.firestore {   match /databases/{database}/documents {
 match /{document=**} {
   allow read: if auth != null;
   allow write: if auth != null;
 }   } }
```

Comment: tried them already but still got the same error message `[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.`

Comment: ussualy every time i open the app, without having a user logon. well the list of product still appear in the app. but right now suddenly i didnt appear anymore. tried to change to last time backup code and still got the same result

Comment: can you able to authenticate and get the uid in this database?
Is the problem happens after changing the rules or the code?

Comment: well i can. the problem come after i try to change my login page from using email into phoneauth. but now i trying to change back into email and password. and after it did some multi verifivation auth using phone number. but ussualy even without having account connect to the app. the list of item still appear

Comment: Did you locally save your uid? 
Better uninstall the application and update the rules in firestore -> click publish it and try to read the documents(show the products) without authentication it won't come then do the login screen flow to get uid and show the products things.

Comment: locally save uid, did that already. deleted the app and install it again? done. well still on the same problem now :')

Comment: so is there any other way to configure? or to fix it?

Comment: Can you share minimal code to check ?

Comment: sure check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72200227/suddenly-cant-fetch-any-data-inside-firebase-firestore-after-trying-to-use-tut?noredirect=1#comment127587582_72200227

Comment: Use the below links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632667/how-do-i-kill-the-process-currently-using-a-port-on-localhost-in-windows/39633428#39633428    and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62684701/how-can-i-shut-down-the-local-firebase-emulators

Comment: after checking all thing, i found out the SHA and SHA-256 was changed, and i tried to download a new google-services.json. and put it in there. well still same problem :')

Comment: @Royalindo I have same problem :( did you resolve it? It's stupid. every conf. right but it doesn't work on android. It's fine on ios

Comment: @RamazanSağır check your project console in and disable your app check. i tried to disable the appcheck but it still doesn't work. and the last thing i do was migrate to a new console project and it works properly

Comment: @Royalindo you right I added app-check configuration to my project but I didn't use it. probably because of it. I will try that. How can I disable app-check. Should I delete the configurations on firebase console?

Comment: On the firebase console, Project Settings>App-Check>APIs>Cloud Firestore click UnEnforce. App-Check was disable then its work. Thanks @Royalindo

Comment: @RamazanSağır no problem :), if the UnEnforce didn't work. migrate to new console project