# http://localhost:8000/ locked to specific project

Tags: redirect, browser, localhost

I've been messing around with several IDEs (eclipse, netbeans, PHPStorm) and I have run into a strange problem. Every time I visit http://localhost:8000/ I see the page from just one of the several projects I've been working on. It's like a redirect has been set up somehow but I have no idea where, or how to change it.

I'm on Windows 10.

Could someone please explain what could be causing this?

Comment: Did you try deinstalling the IDEs, deactivating the services/programs? It would help to know exactly which tool causes this problem, and unless you already have tons of custom settings it might be the easiest way to deinstal them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out some process was using port 8000. I don't know how that happened - I'm guessing one of the IDEs didn't clean up properly when closed. It was solved by this answer: [How do I kill the process currently using a port on localhost in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632667/how-do-i-kill-the-process-currently-using-a-port-on-localhost-in-windows)