# Why am I getting the following error when starting a Java application?

Tags: spring-boot

[image]The application failed to run
Because the port is in use. I don't know which port to close to run the application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I kill the process currently using a port on localhost in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632667/how-do-i-kill-the-process-currently-using-a-port-on-localhost-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there uis another application running on that port, so you can stop it and run your application or change your application port.

in application.yml

```yaml
server:
   port: 8081
```

or application.properties

```
server.port= 8081
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Zahid. But I wanted to run the application to run on port 8080. I terminated the run and removed all terminated runs. Then I ran the application again and it worked.