# I didn't close well a --yarn dev- (Port 4444 is already in use.)

Tags: reactjs, terminal, localhost, next.js, yarnpkg

When I want to run my project next js in localhost I happen to have this problem in the console:

```
yarn run v1.22.10
$ next  dev -p 4444
Port 4444 is already in use.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I closed the tab on the browser without stopping `dev` with `ctrl + c`.

How can I fix this ?  I want to run the project again

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I kill the process currently using a port on localhost in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632667/how-do-i-kill-the-process-currently-using-a-port-on-localhost-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Find the process using

`sudo lsof -i :4444`

It returns you a process id

Kill the process

`kill -9 <PID>`

Comment: 'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Are you using MacOS terminal?

Comment: I am using  cdm terminal on windows In the code editor vscode