# events.js:377 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, server

I've started node js and are simply building a node server.
I put the same code as the picture below in index.js and executed node index.js.
The following error occurred in the terminal below. Can you tell me how to solve it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdEFU.png)

Comment: please paste the code and error output next time

Comment: It says 'permission denied'. You should start the terminal as adminstrator (in windows) or use -sudo in macand linux

Comment: Let me know if this solved your problem

Comment: Thanks for the comment!                                                   I started terminal like what you said but it called same error

Answer (score 1):

You probably already have a node application open at port 8080.

Try changing your port.

You can check if the PORT number is available by using the command:

`netstat -tulnp | grep <port no>`

or you can use lsof:

`lsof -i :<port no>`

Comment: Thanks for the comment!
I tried your code but terminal says
'Command syntax is not correct.'

Comment: Oh, are you using windows? Then try `netstat -ano | findstr :<PORT>` . 

To kill the process, do `taskkill /PID <PID> /F` .
Your <PID> should be the number at the end of the process list.

For more info:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632667/how-do-i-kill-the-process-currently-using-a-port-on-localhost-in-windows

Comment: Also, did you try changing your port number?

Answer (score 1):

You are using restricted port
[image: PORT INFO]
[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers)

try using port 3000

EDIT: You CAN run on a restricted port if you  have admin rights

[image: Admin CMD]

[image: Proof]