# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it with packer for vagrant building with virtualbox

Tags: docker, vagrant, packer, windows-11

I try to create a Vagrant Box (virtualbox) with Packer into Windows 11 OS.
I use a script which run correctly in the past but I don't know why this time I have SSH issue that cause impossible building.

*During the building packer I have this error message :*
`2022/05/30 10:23:51 packer.exe plugin: [DEBUG] TCP connection to SSH ip/port failed: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2619: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

This TCP port number (2619) is random day by day.
*In this example I try to know what application use this port number with those commands* :

```
netstat -an | grep '2619'
netstat -ab | grep '2619' 
netstat -aon | grep '2619'
```

But nothing appear

I use the CurrPorts application to view all TCP/UDP ports in my system. And also I can't view anything about this port number 2619. *But I can see warning on packer.exe line like this* :

[image]

Actually, I use also Docker in my system (not in the same time). But I don't know how parameter port into this.

Why TCP local and remote port does not corresponding to the port number error into packer (2619) ?
Why this port number not appear into netstat commands ?

I understand that connection is forbidden (but access ok) but I don't know why and how authorize this...

Here my config docker desktop :

[image]

[image]

[image]

**How authorize or manage ports for using docker and packer in the same OS (not at the same time) ?**

- No Docker Desktop launched
- disabled firewall Windows
- try with uninstalled docker desktop

I don't know if this message into linux build server dealing with this issue but :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After testing lot of thing, the unique problem is :

**Microsoft Windows 11 update (KB5012592)**

For resolving that you need to :

**stop using Hyper-V component windows** (I never do something other. It's just this in my context)

More info here :

- [microsoft forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/latest-win-11-updates-causing-total-fault-of/071ed218-394c-46fd-ba55-e7cf7eaa0fc7)
- [Oracle VirtualBox issue](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/20943)

Answer (score -1):

Docker does not create it's own port, it must be a given with the -p command.
Like, docker run -d -p 8080:80 -
Map TCP port 80 in the container to port 8080 on the Docker host.

About the netstat -aon | grep '2619.
I am pretty sure that windows are using findstr command and not grep.
After using findstr you should get a PID of the process which you can use taskkill

See more here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39633428/10814912

Comment: Docker uninstall has not impact to my issue and Windows command for finding port dealing with issue return nothing.