# EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I am running a very simple node code and I'm not using any other project, every time im running node server.js i got this error :
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000
But at the same time im not using any other project or server

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("Server has started on port 5000");
});
```

Comment: Just try to kill that port first ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39633428/12715723))

Comment: I tried to kill the server but it is still working somehow

Comment: Are you using mac os?

Comment: yes im using mac

Comment: BRO thank you, it worked i have no idea about that, thank you so much buddy

Comment: @kennarddh how i can accept your answer ?

Answer (score -1):

That means you already have a service running on the same port.
So you have to shutdown(kill) that service(process).
To kill the process, you must know process id.
To check process id, type this cmd `ps -ah`.
And you will see the running node process and its pid(process id).

The final thing is to kill process, type `kill (pid)`

Comment: ps -ah
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
  646 ttys000    0:00.01 /usr/bin/login -fqpl jj /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/ShellLauncher --launch_shell
  647 ttys000    0:00.41 -zsh
 6757 ttys000    0:00.01 ps -ah
 3585 ttys002    0:00.10 /bin/zsh -il
 3611 ttys003    0:00.03 /bin/zsh -il
 5935 ttys004    0:00.04 -zsh

Comment: i kill this as you said but ➜ kill 5000
kill: kill 5000 failed: no such process

Comment: ➜ kill 5935
kill: kill 5935 failed: no such process

Comment: You shouldn't blindly kill processes.