# The listener for function 'Functions.timerTrigger1' was unable to start. Azure.Storage.Blobs: Service request failed. Status: 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: azure-functions

While running azure time trigger function app getting the status 403 forbidden error. I have ran the storage emulator by "AzureStorageEmulator.exe start" command, but still getting the same error.

Any suggestions would be helpful

[image]

When I run a storage emulator, there are no containers are getting created under the blob container. Is this the root cause for getting the above error?

Comment: please share your code

Comment: please share the code that you tried@Shireesha in c# ,PYTHON, Javascripit or typsript. The error in the test and the screenshot

Comment: Please do not post images of code or errors. Text is preferred so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

- Install Azurite using the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=npm).

[image]

[image]

- From the above command we can check Storage Emulator  running on port number `10000`.

[image]

- The port is already used so we need to start the Emulator with a new port number or [kill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39633428) the existing process running with that port number with the below command.

[image]

- After terminating use the command
  `AzureStorageEmulator.exe start -inprocess` to start.
- Adding a  new port number.

[image]

[image]

- For more details refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632667/how-do-i-remove-the-process-currently-using-a-port-on-localhost-in-windows/39633428#39633428).