# Unable to debug azure function app locally

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

In my function app, there are 2 functions(python) which I am trying to debug. I am using VS Code as my IDE.

[See 2 functions here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFTov.png)

While debugging, I am getting error,
`[2023-12-17T07:31:33.598Z]     raise RuntimeError(str(endpoints["error"])) [2023-12-17T07:31:33.599Z] RuntimeError: Can't listen for client connections: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted [2023-12-17T07:31:33.613Z] Language Worker Process exited. Pid=25436.`
And soon after this I am getting prompt

[See error prompt here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Q6HV.png)

I am not able to find much information about this and any help/guidance is much appreciated.

I tried closing the VS Code and tried debugging again and it seems to be working but then while passing parametes(in json) I was getting error `Parse Error: Expected HTTP/`.
I have also tried removing and then re-cloning repo just to see if that makes any difference but still end up with error `[WinError 10048]`.

Comment: The error you're encountering, "WinError 10048," indicates that the socket address (protocol/network address/port) is already in use. This can happen when there is another process using the same port that your Azure Functions runtime is trying to bind to.

Comment: Can you share the code you are trying?

Comment: Can you confirm, which function's model you are using v1 or v2?

Comment: I can see version to be 2.0 in host.json.

I wont be able to share the code since it is very large and spread across multiple files, hope that makes sense.

Comment: I am not able to figure out which other application is trying to access the default azure function port(7071). Also, whenever I am closing the VS Code and debugging it again, it works just for one time and post that I get "Win Error 10048".

Comment: As mentioned, there are 2 functions in my functionApp could that cause this error as they might be trying to access same port when invoked? (just thinking out loud here).

Comment: Yes this is the issue. Refer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632667/how-do-i-remove-the-process-currently-using-a-port-on-localhost-in-windows) SO answers to kill the process running on specific ports If any.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like both your Functions when triggered are running on the same port. In order to resolve this error. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632667/how-do-i-remove-the-process-currently-using-a-port-on-localhost-in-windows) SO thread answer to kill the existing process from your local laptop that is utilizing the Azure Functions port. After killing the process. Restart your Function again with **fn+F5** or **control + F5**. Or **Run and Debug** then open both of your triggered Functions in the browser.

I tried replicating your Function with the sample code below:-

**Code :**

```py
import azure.functions as func
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)

@app.route(route="GenerateAlerts")
def GenerateAlerts(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )

@app.route(route="ProcessAllProjectDeliverables", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
def ProcessAllProjectDeliverables(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )
```

**launch.json :**

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to Python Functions",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9091,
            "preLaunchTask": "func: host start"
        }
    ]
}
```

**My function output:-**

It ran successfully with two HTTP trigger functions as below,

[image]

**Browser output of both functions:**

*I got the below output for the first HTTP trigger function,*

[image]
[image]

*And below is the output for the second HTTP trigger function,*

[image]
[image]