# After killing process the port 8080 is still in use

Tags: java, tomcat

I tried to run SpringBoot application in IntelliJ IDEA but got an error:

```
Web server failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use.
```

I tried to terminate a process that used 8080 port but after successfully killing it restarted automatically within several seconds with new PID. I found out that it is some java proccess but I can not understand what application restarts this java proccess.

Restarting PC does not help.

Could anyone help to identify what application uses 8080 port?

**Update**

It was Jenkins. I opened http://localhost:8080/ and saw its default page. Then, I checked my Windows Services and found the Jenkins service that had launched automatically. After stopping it, the 8080 port became free, and my Spring Boot app (Tomcat server) ran successfully.

Thank you, everyone, for your support.

Comment: Could be Jenkins?

Comment: I have killed the process with 11128 PID but port 8080 is still used with a process with 10676 PID.

Comment: With regards to "*restarting the PC does not help*", check your startup apps.

Comment: I have only 4 apps (including antivirus) that have 'Enabled' status on  Task Manager -> Startup tab. None of them look suspicious.

Comment: Can you get the full command line of the java process in order to find out what exactly is executed? Also, the parent process could help.

Comment: And not all applications running at startup are listed in task manager. I think there are other locations to look at like task scheduler.

Comment: This seems to be some process that was started as service. Services often do have a restart policy (i.e. they are started again automatically if they are killed). "tasklist /svc" will give you information which service this is.

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].

Comment: did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632667/how-do-i-remove-the-process-currently-using-a-port-on-localhost-in-windows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove the process currently using a port on localhost in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632667/how-do-i-remove-the-process-currently-using-a-port-on-localhost-in-windows)

Comment: No, it is not the answer for my questions because I wrote that just killing the process didn't help. In the 'update' section of my question I wrote what helped me.