# Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (management.azure.com:443)

Tags: azure, powershell

I am using the official Az Powershell module. I am using latest Powershell 7.4.1

Randomly I am getting the following error:

```
ErrorRecord                 : Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (management.azure.com:443)
WasThrownFromThrowStatement : False
TargetSite                  : System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject] Invoke(System.Collections.IEnumerable)
Message                     : The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (management.azure.com:443)
Data                        : {[System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrameInfo, System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrameInfo[]]}
InnerException              :
HelpLink                    :
Source                      : System.Management.Automation
HResult                     : -2146233087
StackTrace                  :    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
                                 at Microsoft.PowerShell.Executor.ExecuteCommandHelper(Pipeline tempPipeline, Exception& exceptionThrown, ExecutionOptions options)
```

The error occurs on the following cmdlets for me. Other cmdlets might be affected as well.

```
Get-AzRoleDefinition
Get-AzRoleAssignment
Get-AzSubscription
Get-AzManagementGroup
```

No other users are logged on to the machine and only a single instance of Powershell is running. All sessions to Azure are disconnected after the script finishes and reopen if the script runs once more.

Sometimes the script runs without any issues, sometimes the error happens right at the beginning, sometimes at the end. The error can occur right after opening a fresh Powershell window also.

I am making well under 100 calls against Azure, nothing that could exhaust the local available ports.

Open port 443 connections during the time of the error:

```
netstat -ano | findstr :443
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25203     13.107.213.45:443      ESTABLISHED     4332
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25218     20.190.190.100:443     ESTABLISHED     13392
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25221     92.123.151.23:443      ESTABLISHED     4332
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25227     51.116.150.70:443      TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25232     51.116.156.32:443      TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25234     51.116.150.70:443      ESTABLISHED     13392
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25237     51.116.156.32:443      TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25239     51.116.156.32:443      TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25240     13.107.246.45:443      CLOSE_WAIT      4332
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25249     204.79.197.239:443     ESTABLISHED     4332
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25250     20.42.73.28:443        ESTABLISHED     4332
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25254     51.116.150.70:443      TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25259     20.190.159.23:443      ESTABLISHED     4332
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25260     51.116.150.70:443      ESTABLISHED     13392
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25289     51.116.150.70:443      TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25290     34.252.119.145:443     ESTABLISHED     4332
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25293     20.190.190.100:443     ESTABLISHED     13392
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25294     51.116.156.32:443      TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25303     95.101.150.2:443       ESTABLISHED     4332
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25323     40.126.31.69:443       ESTABLISHED     13392
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25325     51.116.150.70:443      ESTABLISHED     13392
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25332     20.190.190.100:443     ESTABLISHED     13392
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25338     20.190.190.100:443     ESTABLISHED     13392
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25345     20.50.88.233:443       ESTABLISHED     13392
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25350     20.190.190.100:443     ESTABLISHED     13392
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25351     51.116.150.70:443      TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25356     20.42.73.28:443        ESTABLISHED     4332
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25360     51.116.156.32:443      TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25366     51.116.150.70:443      ESTABLISHED     13392
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25370     20.50.201.195:443      ESTABLISHED     4332
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25372     51.116.156.32:443      TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25376     40.126.31.69:443       TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25380     51.116.150.70:443      ESTABLISHED     13392
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25390     51.116.150.70:443      TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    10.0.0.0:25393     51.116.156.32:443      TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    10.0.0.0:49154     20.103.246.163:443     TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    10.0.0.0:49156     52.178.17.234:443      TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    10.0.0.0:49158     20.42.65.89:443        TIME_WAIT       0
```

`management.azure.com` resolves to `51.116.150.70`, which has 10 open connections, all in use of process `13392` which is my Powershell window (`pwsh.exe`). So there is no other process conflicting.

Comment: In your case port 443 is using another process. You can check if the port in your program is already in use by another program. If it's in use, you can either use a different port or terminate the active process to free up the port. Here is the command to check the port: **netstat -ano | findstr :443**

Comment: @VenkatV I don't think this applies since I am issuing commands against Azure, so outgoing sessions. You can have multiple HTTPS outbound connections open against 443

Comment: Find out which processes are connected to management.azure.com 115.112.18.21 on port 443. If there is any process that is already active, terminate it and try again.

Comment: @VenkatV Please see my update, the Powershell window is the only one having connections to Azure

Comment: Kill the process using the command: **taskkill /PID 13392 /F**. Once the process is killed, try running the command again. refer the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632667/how-do-i-remove-the-process-currently-using-a-port-on-localhost-in-windows)

Comment: @VenkatV Why would I kill the process where I am trying to issue the command that is generating the problem? As I said when closing down the Powershell and opening it up again, the error still occurs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256879/discussion-between-venkat-v-and-david-trevor).